# Why can't you develop android TV apps for versions below android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-tv

Android studio doesn't allow to develop android TV apps to versions below android 5.0 (API 21) is there a specific reason?

Is there any way of developing an android TV app for an android TV that has 4.42 kitkat in it? Or is there a way to change the developed app to an older sdks/api version?

I tried this, but it didn't work for me

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"
    android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
```

Comment: please clarify "it doesn't do anything"

Comment: doesn't work on devices above sdks level 14 - 23 @Kuffs

Comment: I don't think android TV works below 5.0

Comment: As far as I know, there are no Android TV devices running versions earlier than 5. The maifest entries you specified would still be accepted though so it is still not clear exactly what it is that "does not work"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_TV.  I have an app in Play store now that targets Android 4 on phones but has a TV component also that works on Android TV.

Comment: If you need to run it on 4.4 then its not Android TV its Android 4.4

Comment: You can add another module to the app that will be loaded separately onto TVs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no Android TV devices running versions earlier than 5. The manifest entries you specified would still be accepted though so it is still not clear exactly what it is that "does not work" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_TV.

I have an app in Play store now that targets Android 4 on phones but has a TV component also that works on Android TV.

Most likely your issue is the targetSDK. You are saying you want to compile your app with API14. You cannot do this and also support Android TV because all Android TV commands were introduced in API21

Comment: Android TV (as in Google's official variation of the generic Android OS intended for TV devices) indeed started with Android 5.0, so there are no Android TV devices pre 5.0.

There are however many set-top boxes (often low-end Chinese brands) and some TVs (some Philips 2014 models for instance) which run on earlier versions of Android. That however is not "Android TV": those run either the tablet version of Android or custom interfaces.

In addition, there is the much older initiative by Google called Google TV, which never caught on and is no longer relevant.

Comment: I think previous iterations were called "Google TV".  I wasn't totally sure as I receive crash reports from my Android TV app that is running on Android 4 and obviously is not supported on that platform.

Comment: Updated my previous comment to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that when you define

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true" />
```

It won't run on TVs unless --someday they have touchscreens.

For AndroidTV (**not** Amazon FireTV) may

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />
```

is also required to be true.

Comment: This would only affect whether the app would be available to install from Play Store as it would cause any devices without the listed capabilities to be filtered out.

Comment: Ah, I see! It would also not be available from the leanbacklauncher, but should be available through installed apps.